# "success_action_redirect" does not work in authenticated request for browser-based upload file to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask

I am new to aws S3 and I am trying to build a web app that allows a user to directly upload a file to S3 using boto3.

The user first sends request to my own server (e.g. https://example.com), and my web app (written in python Flask) has a form to allow the user to upload a file. This app will then allow the user to upload a file directly to S3 using authenticated request (AWS authenticate signature version4).

I basically followed the steps in this URL (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python). 
Note that I did not use Heroku to build my web server. I have my own server on the other hosing company.

So the code works when I don't assign "success_action_redirect" in the Fields and Conditions. 
If I want to redirect the user to my own server, if uploading successful. The code won't work. The error message is shown as follows.

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://test1.s3.amazonaws.com/. Cross-origin redirection denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy."
```

Here is the python code block I have.

```
@app.route('/sign_s3/')
def sign_s3():
    file_name = 'testfd/' + request.args.get('file_name')
    file_type = request.args.get('file_type')
    s3 = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=AWS_ID,aws_secret_access_key=AWS_KEY)

    presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(Bucket = AWS_BUCKET, \
    Key = file_name,Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type, "success_action_redirect":"https://example.com" }, \
    Conditions = [{"acl": "public-read"},{"Content-Type": file_type}, { "success_action_redirect": "https://example.com"}],\

    ExpiresIn = 3600)

    result_json = json.dumps({'data': presigned_post,\
    'url': 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (AWS_BUCKET, file_name)})

    return result_json
```

In addition, here is the CORS configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin> https://example.com </AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I've looked discussions on other posts, but none of them work. I have also tried both options in Conditions, it still does not work. Any thought is appreciated!

```
{"success_action_redirect": "https://example.com"} or  {"success_action_redirect": "https://example.com/uploadOK.html"}
```